# Rendering fields manually and custom css class

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am trying to manually render the form fields.

I would like to add a bootstrap and custom css class to rendered html.

How can I do this ?

**forms.py**

```
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Order

        fields = ['name','postal_code']
        widgets = {
            'postal_code': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

**file.html**

```
 <form action="." method="post" class="order-form">    
 <div class="fieldWrapper">
    {{ form.postal_code }}
 </div>
 <p><input type="submit" value="Send"></p>
    {% csrf_token %}
 </form>
{% endblock %}
```

**rendered html**

```
 <div class="fieldWrapper">
    <ul id="id_postal_code">
    <li><label for="id_postal_code_0"><input type="radio" name="postal_code" value="Yes" required id="id_postal_code_0" />Yes</label></li>
    <li><label for="id_postal_code_1"><input type="radio" name="postal_code" value="No" required id="id_postal_code_1" />No</label></li>
    </ul>
 </div>
```

How to solve a problem ?

I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add css classes to form fields in the following way:

```
    'postal_code': forms.RadioSelect(attrs={"class": "form-control"}),
```

Another option is to not render the form this way at all, and just write your own html.

Comment: A good idea. What about other fields? For example: name? Do I have to add attr to the Model ? I do not understand. Because I have my own html. What do you mean ?

Comment: By writing the html, i mean doing the `<input class="..."/>` stuff yourself for complete contol. Also possibly look into django-crispy-forms for more control over style.

Comment: That's exactly what I mean. <Input class = "..." /> and full control. But I dont know how to get data from Model.

Comment: did you see this in the documentation: [Creating custom fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#creating-custom-fields)